# Highcharts Legend 'enabled' function not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Below is the script i've written for Highchart to enable/disable Legend on specific condition. But it isn't working.

```
               legend: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                itemStyle: { color: '#333333', cursor: 'none', fontSize: '10px', fontWeight: 'normal' },
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    return this.name;
                },
                enabled: function () {
                    if (ChartType == "column") {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
```

Seems like the function is not calling at all. If i mention 'enabled : true', it works just fine.. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to shift condition into Highchart post-processing:

```
var type = 'show', display = true;
if (ChartType == "column") {
    type = 'hide';
    display = false;
}

chart.legend.group[type]();
chart.legend.box[type]();
chart.legend.display = display;
chart.legend.render();
```

Comment: Thnq. Answer/Comment by @Võ Minh Phong . fix the issue

Comment: @SandeepMogaveer, both of them are right, up to you

Answer (score 0):

Type of `enabled` is Boolean, so you can't set it a function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.enabled

Comment: Oh.. Right. Is there any workaround you can suggest ?

Comment: You can declare a variable, like enable, you set default false, you declare a function run before you process Chart.
`function () {
                    if (ChartType == "column") {
                        enable = true;
                    } else {
                        enable = false;
                    }`